# Malformed UTF-8 characters in Slim Framework v3

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, slim, utf8mb4

I did an **API** with **Slim Framework** and I get data from **MySQL** database which is encoded with *utf8mb4_unicode_ci*.

When I was programming, I was using **PHP v7**. To get data in a right way, I had to insert code below at the top of my **API** code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.utf-8", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8'); // I need it because I use mb_ereg_replace to replace with a regex in UTF-8.
```

With this all data was returned in right way, so I didn't need to use `utf8_encode` or `utf8_decode` function. But after install it inside the official server, which has **PHP v5.6**, I got:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details

Type: RuntimeException
Code: 5
Message: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded
File: Slim/Http/Response.php
Line: 318
```

I don't know how to fix it... I really think it's a problem with PHP v5.6, maybe? Or Slim Framework? Or is there another way to work with *utf8mb4_unicode_ci* in PHP v5.6?!

**EDIT**

I did all right, but when I was looking with more attention to code the problem was when I was calling strtotime function, so I've tried to use `uft8_encode`, `mb_*` functions and also `uft8_decode` to fix the problem but nothing worked, so I had to strip accents in another function that I created. Now it's everyting working well.

Comment: So... what generates this error? The encoding code is nice but we need more info

Comment: Get rid of all calls to `mb_*` routines.  Then check the "best practices" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/38363567/1766831

Comment: @Machavity @Rick James I did all right, but when I was looking with more attention to code the problem was when I was calling strtotime function, so I've tried to use `uft8_encode`, `mb_*` functions and also `uft8_decode` to fix the problem but nothing worked, so I had to strip accents in another function that I created. Now it's everyting working well.

Answer (score 3):

Access the "src" folder, where you will find the "dependencies" file.

Find the line:

```
$pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=" . $settings['host'] . ";dbname=" . $settings['dbname'],
```

Add to it:

> .";charset=UTF8"

It would look like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO ("mysql:host=" . $settings['host'] . ";dbname=". $settings['dbname'].";charset=UTF8",
```

Answer (score 2):

In my index.php I wrote:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbname; charset=UTF8', user, pass);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer, like how your answer relates to the original question